# Coercing an object to a number - how is it?

Tags: javascript

I read an article on coercing objects to primitives and it said that JavaScript first tries to convert an object to a string. If it fails, then it tries to convert it to a number. But I can't imagine converting an object to a number, or does it mean arrays? Since arrays are objects it's totally clear to me. But if it means objects like `obj = {a: 1}` then I'd like to get some examples, please.

Comment: You can coerce straight to a number with `+` - `+{a: 1}` -> `NaN` (not a number). But your question itself makes no sense - if you can't imagine converting an object to a number, and you know arrays are objects, then what's "totally clear"?

Comment: if it coerces to a number then why the result is NaN? Doesnt it mean that this object can't be converted to a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it does convert, but **only** for an object that has a `valueOf` mehtod that returns a **number** or a **numeric string** (e.g., "234") or a `toString` method that also returns a **numeric string**. Otherwise you'll get a `NaN` which means `Not a Number` but ironically `typeof NaN = "number"`.

```js
const obj = {
  valueOf: () => 234
}

// credit: @pilchard
const another_obj = {
  toString: () => "123"
}

const num_a = +obj;
const num_b = +another_obj;

console.log(num_a, num_b);
```

Comment: it could also be a `toString()` method